# Programmatically determine if a tie is possible in US elections

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-complete, dynamic-programming, recurrence-relation

Problem 3.5 from book: "Algorithms for interviews".

There are 51 states (+ Washington DC), each with different amount of votes. Find the number of votes of each state [here](https://www.britannica.com/topic/United-States-Electoral-College-Votes-by-State-1787124)

Suppose there are two candidates in the presidential election. How would you programmatically determine if a tie is a possibility. The problem is in dynamic programming section.

Solution:
We need to find out if there is a subset in the set of 51 state-votes such that its elements add up to 269. The number of possible subsets is 2^51, so bruteforce solution is out of question.

My approach is the following: Let `P(i,c)[0 < i < n, 0 < c < 269]` be a node in a graph. `i` represents the state index, `c` represents votes **left** to reach 269.

Each `P(i, c)` has two children: `P(i + 1, c), P(i + 1, c - V(i))` where `V(i)` is list of state-votes(i.e. either state `i` votes for our candidate or it doesn't). This leads to a graph(a tree actually) which interestingly has same amount of nodes as there are subsets: 2^51.

Starting from `P(0, 269)`, we do BFS until all states are exhausted or **c == 0**

The solution is quick with only ~20k nodes discovered(instead of 2^51) but I have a few doubts.

1. Worst case scenario of this solution has exponential complexity. Is this an NP complete problem?
2. Is there a better solution. Even if it's np complete, can we do better?
3. How can I model this problem with recurrence relation instead of graph?

Solution in Java:

```
    public boolean run() {
        List<Integer> stateVotes = List.of(9,3,10,6,55,9,7,3,27,15,4,4,21,11,7,6,8,9,4,10,12,17,10,6,11,3,5,5,4,15,5,31,15,3,20,7,7,21,4,8,3,11,34,5,3,13,11,5,10,3,3);

        //bfs
        var visited = new HashSet<Node>();
        var queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
        queue.add(new Node(0, 269));

        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            var node = queue.pop();
            if (node.y == 0) {
                return true;
            }

            if (visited.contains(node)) {
                continue;
            }
            visited.add(node);

            if (node.x < stateVotes.size() - 1) {
                queue.add(new Node(node.x + 1, node.y));
                queue.add(new Node(node.x + 1, node.y - stateVotes.get(node.x)));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You can solve this using routine dynamic programming.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus could you please explain how? As far as I understand, it will lead to "isomorphic" solution to mine

Comment: Right, your solution is the routine dynamic programming approach. Your problem is known as PARTITION or SUBSET SUM, and a lot is known about it. You can start with the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus interesting. Thanks a lot  for the lead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is known as PARTITION, which is a special case of the well-known problem [SUBSET SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). Your algorithm is the standard dynamic programming solution. You can find a wealth of information on SUBSET SUM all over the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a bit array of say 600 entries, initially with bit 0 set. This array represents the possible number of votes from the first n state, for n = 0 initially.

Take the first state. If it has for example 13 votes, then set array[I+13] = 1 for all elements where a[I] is set. So that would give you bits 0 and 13 set - from the first state you can have either 0 or 13 votes.

Take the second state. If it has for example 9 votes, then set array[I+9] = 1 for all elements where a[I] is set. So that would give you bits 0, 9, 13 and 22. From the first two states you can have 0, 9, 13 or 22 votes.

Repeat with all the other states, and then check whether bit 269 is set. It turns out if all electoral votes go to the same party, then any votes other than 1 or 2, or all but one or two, are possible. But in Maine and Nebraska the votes can be split, and it is possible to have 1 or 2 electoral votes in these states, so every outcome is actually possible.